# how to download the sample influxdb database in windows environment?

Tags: influxdb

I am running influxdb in windows environment. I want some influxdb sample data to run some tests? is there any tutorial or documentation on how to add sample data to influxdb database in windows ?

Comment: import huge amount of data, following this https://medium.com/@eyebool/creating-a-sample-database-for-influxdb-102a89464132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding data to InfluxDB should be independent of which operating system that you're working with. InfluxData provides some [sample data](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.1/query_language/data_download/) that is used throughout their documentation.